# Spring boot + mvc (rest) + angularJS: add security

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I have a web application with separate front and back:

```
/project  
+--- /back
+--- /front
```

The back is developped using Spring boot + Spring MVC, while the front is using AngularJS.

I am trying to set up the security for the communication between the back/front. What I did:

```
- create a ConfigSecurity class which extends from WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
- create a SpringWebMvcInitializer which extends from AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer and call ConfigSecurity
- create a SecurityWebInitializer class which extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer
```

My ConfigSecurity looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class ConfigSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/demo/**","/home").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("...")
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

My problems:

1. In `configureGlobal()`, I can set the username and password to access my protected urls, but how can I do when there is not only one single user? I mean, I want to grant access to all the users that are registered in my database.
2. Since the back and the front are only communicating with REST (through JSON files), what should be done with `formLogin()` in `ConfigSecurity`? By default, Spring Security generates a default login form. I don't need a it in the back of the application since it is the front which is responsible for displaying the loginPage. How can I skip the login page in the back? Maybe by putting the username and password in JSON file the front is sending to the back? Does someone know how it can be done?

I am using Java Configuration for Spring (not XML configuration).

Comment: Please check this tutorial https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/12/the-login-page-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-ii it should explain how to login from AngularJS application.

Answer (score 2):

You have many options, all of them require quite a lot of code, but most of it is already well implemented around the internet so you just would have to make it fit your needs. You can either go with simplest way which would be http sessions, JSON token or JWT (JSON web token) or anything else.

- Spring blog has a very long post about how to implement different
  solutions here:
  https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/
- JHipster also has different authentication methods which you can take a look at. They have very well implemented role security in front-end which I like a lot and would really suggest looking into: https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app
- Here's also a JWT which is requires the most code: http://blog.jdriven.com/2014/10/stateless-spring-security-part-2-stateless-authentication/

HTTP Sessions would definitely be the easiest to set up and is well supported by Spring Security out of the box already.

Answer (score 0):

Found great help on this [baeldung website](http://www.baeldung.com/security-spring) (even though it is using XML configuration) and [this website](http://java.dzone.com/articles/secure-rest-services-using) (using Java configuration).

For global explanation of how Spring security works, [this link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/technical-overview.html#tech-intro-web-authenticationBlockquoteBlockquote) helps me a lot.